# Trouble using with-min

Tags: netlogo

A simple question, but one I'm totally failing on.

I have a group of turtles that need to locate the nearest neighbour, as I wish to create a link between them. I've tried the following code, but I keep coming back with a null set [nobody found]:

```
ask turtles [create-links-with one-of other turtles with-min [distance myself]]
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Regards

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here.

One is that `create-links-with` is wrong because `one-of` returns a single agent, not an agentset. You need `create-link-with`.

But the main problem is with this part:

```
 other turtles with-min [...]
```

NetLogo understands this as `other (turtles with-min [...])`. This reports an empty agentset, because the turtle itself wins the `with-min` competition because its distance is zero, then `other` eliminates that turtle, leaving the empty agentset.

Instead, you must write:

```
(other turtles) with-min [...]
```

So with both fixes together, we get:

```
ask turtles [
  create-link-with one-of (other turtles) with-min [distance myself]
]
```

If you want, this can be further shortened further by using `min-one-of` instead of `with-min`, like this:

```
ask turtles [
  create-link-with min-one-of other turtles [distance myself]
]
```

I made some turtles and tried it out in NetLogo's Command Center, and I got:

[image: preview]